# Extra thin black line on the sides of my dotted border when applying border-radius

Tags: html, css

I would like to have a dotted border effect but when using `border-radius` the rendered effect is not perfect. I mean there is some extra thin black line on the sides. How to avoid this ?

[image]

```css
code {
  background-color: #040404;
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding: 2px 3px;
  font-weight: 100 !important;
  font-size: small !important;
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: white !important;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  border-style: dotted;
  border-color: white;
  border-width: initial;
}
```

```html
<code>COMING SOON</code>
```

Comment: The thin black border seems to be a rounding error in the browser's rendering of curved borders. You can likely do nothing about it via CSS (aside from using images, like SVG or PNG - at least that would look the same in all modern browsers).